# Limiting process memory usage with systemd-run not working as expected

Tags: systemd, memory, cgroups

I'm trying to limit the memory usage of Chrome with systemd-run by starting it with:

```
systemd-run --scope \
  -p MemoryMax=16G \
  -p MemoryHigh=15G \
  -p CPUWeight=70 \
  -p StartupCPUWeight=100 \
  /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

However this seems to not really work, as I can see it filling up all my 32GB of ram and crashing my system. It appears to me like Systemd is not registering all the memory actually used. Does anyone know what could be missing here and or how to limit that otherwise? This is on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

[image: screenshot with the output of systemd status vs top]

Any hint is much appreciated.

Edit: Seems I was looking at the wrong column in the results from top and therefore my suspicion was in the wrong direction. The actual bottleneck must be another process and systemd-run is doing it's job. Thank you @marcus-müller for your insight.

Comment: that's just virtual memory, not actually allocated memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's just virtual memory, not actually allocated memory; things seem to be working well.

Comment: The system is still becoming unresponsive from the memory usage. Maybe my suspect is wrong, if the top command doesn't provide the information I thought it did.. Doesn't the TOP command provide the actual memory usage? If not, how may I find the actual culprit?

Comment: It does provide it, but you're looking at the wrong column!

Comment: and what would be the correct column?  RES?

Comment: RES, but you might have to subtract up to SHR (because top can't know how much of the allocated shareable memory is actually shared)